# z-index issue in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, z-index

I am trying to call one div on click of select element. there are 4 select elements two in each row. When that div is called it goes behind the succesive select element. This issue is specific to IE7. It works fine with IE8 and firefox3. 
please can anybody help...
Thanks,

Comment: The div which I am trying to call is absolutely positioned.

Comment: Post some of the source code you have already written. That should make it easier for others to understand the problem and help you

Answer (score 1):

You can read the following link for a detailed info

[How the Z-index Attribute Works for HTML Elements](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177378)

There are two work around for this.

The first is to hide the select element when the div appears. This might not be a good solution.

The other better solutions is to place an iframe at the same position as that of the div.

The iFrame must be added at the end of the page so that it appears in front of all other windowed controls (the windowed controls are stacked in the order in which they appear on the page). That takes care of covering any SELECT that may be in our way.

You can have a look at the code in the page

[Bug Fix: SELECT box displayed through Dynamic DIV in Internet Explorer](http://xlib.wordpress.com/2006/04/12/bug-fix-select-box-displayed-through-dynamic-div-in-internet-explorer/)